Sitecore Archive Menu Not Displaying All Options
In the Sitecore 9.2 content editor, the Archive menu on the Review ribbon has stopped showing the Archive Item and Archive Version commands for our contributor-level users.  It's working fine for administrative-level users (distinct, I should mention, from Sitecore admins).
This seems to imply a difference in permissions, but I can't find any difference for the item being archived and know of no recent changes to the permission structure for that content. Is there somewhere, perhaps in the Core database or web config, where the visibility of the archive menu items is controlled?

In order to check access, try switching to CORE database (bottom right corner of desktop view).
Then go to access viewer (via launchpad)
Select the role you are interested in or a single user. Then expand the tree to find this location:
/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Menues/Archive/Archive Item Now

If you see a red cross against Read, then click that icon. It should give you further information about why they are unable to access on the right hand side/


Enlightening stuff, but so far I haven't been able to find it.  According to the Access Viewer, the user should be able to see these menu items.  I've checked all the roles the user belongs to as well, for completeness.  Anything else which might affect this?

You can check for the access on the menu items beneath below item, for the contributor level users in the core database.
/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Menues/Archive

This can be checked in the Access Viewer section on the user through checking they have read rights on these menu items.
By default Sitecore Client Authoring role provides the read access on these menu items. You can check whethere contributor-level users are a member of this role.

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.
